# Does setting an object reference equal to null in an array of references, delete it completely from the memory in java? If not, then how?

Tags: java, arrays, object, reference, nullpointerexception

How can I delete an object reference completely from an array of references from the memory in Java? I was setting it's value to null but I am not sure of how things are working under the hood.

I tried to iterate through the array using for loop to reach to the specific index from where I had to delete the object reference and then shift all the other references to the left by one position each.

Comment: Once there are no references to an object, it will eventually be garbage collected. So if that array had the only reference to your object, then yes.

Comment: Your question is somewhat ambiguous.  Do you want the _reference_ to be removed from memory, OR are you talking about the object the reference points to? What is your reason for wanting to control this?  This may be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 0):

If the object variable you set to null, and no other object variable is referencing to that object any more than it will be picked up by garbage collector in jvm at some point, but we don't have to worry about it.

Refer to this question:

[How does Garbage Collection identify orphaned objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60930083/how-does-garbage-collection-identify-orphaned-objects)